# XBox One Wireless Adapter availability

Tags: game-controller, wireless-adapter, xbox-one

On 20th October 2015 Microsoft released the Wireless Adapter for PC, which allows to connect XBox One Wireless Controllers to a PC.

However, while there were many news about the upcoming release of the adapter, the availability of this adapter is very poor.

Personally, i waited months for the release of the adapter, preordered it on amazon and was already surprised when the supposed delivery date was the 27th October instead of 20th. On the 27th amazon declared that the item is not available and without information about availability in the future.

I tried to find informations about a shortage of adapters following a too high demand, but could only find other users complaining about not receiving the adapter on the "promised" date. Other online shops also switched the status to "not available".

I went to one of the biggest retail markets for tech stuff in Germany, whose online site declared the adapter available, but i was told that it was an error in their online system. They never received any of the ordered adapters.

Why are there no big news about the not existing availability of a highly wanted item? As far as i know the XBox One Elite controller also is not available on the release date, same as "XBox One Wireless Controller + PC Adapter" bundle.

Or is this problem only restricted to germany and other places in the world got their adapters?

Answer (score 0):

No your not alone i've not received mine yet. Have ordered from amazon UK and from a German store amazon tracking has my item last seen in France on the 27th Nov. Groove land of Germany sent me an email today saying we regret our order has not turned up so we can not ship item, will ship as soon as possible

Comment: Your experience is a data point, but not really a definitive answer.  It might be more appropriate as a comment, which requires a little more rep.